# Haskell : Parse error on "|" in otherwise

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile the following code, but am getting a "parse error on "|" in the otherwise statement"

Now I am confused as I have used pretty much similar syntax in a few other functions, the only difference being this one takes 2 elements on a list and tries to reconstruct one (FYI: Did not test it yet as I can't compile, so the code in the convertElements line might be wrong!)

I am using spaces, and everything seems aligned. Any idea as to what would be causing it? I moved it to the bottom of the where in case it helped, but alas it did not.

```
convertElements :: [(String, String, String)] -> [(String, String, String)]
convertElements [] = []
convertElements (x:y:xs) = x: (a,b,c) : convertElements((a,b,c) ++ xs)
                    where b = (getSecond y)
                          c = (getThird y)
                          a | if ((containsDash (getThird x)) > 0) then last (getThird x)
                            | otherwise = (getFirst y)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close but not quite with the guard syntax, which does not use the `if`/`then`/`else` keywords.

```
convertElements :: [(String, String, String)] -> [(String, String, String)]
convertElements [] = []
convertElements (x:y:xs) = x : (a,b,c) : convertElements ((a,b,c) : xs)
  where b = getSecond y
        c = getThird y
        a | containsDash (getThird x) > 0 = last (getThird x)
          | otherwise = getFirst y
```

Comment: Ah I see, I will remember that next time. No ifs with guards unless fully completed (with else).

Answer (score 2):

To expand a bit on @ephemient's answer: `|` *can* be followed by `if ...` but that makes `if`-expression the guard, so the compiler is expecting to see

```
 a | if ... then ... else ... = ...
```

But the second `|` shows up before `else` does, so you get an error there.

Comment: Ah this makes a lot of sense, thanks for the extra input :)
Does that mean that ALL if statements require an else in Haskell? Can't I just have it as if this then do that ?

Comment: @Pain `if`/`then`/`else` is an expression. If there is only a `then` case, what is the type of the expression when `if` is not true? 
Now, sometimes the result is discardable. For example, there is the `when :: Monad m => Bool -> m () -> m ()` function, which is equivalent to `return ()` if the condition is false.

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
a | ...condition... = ...value...
  | otherwise       = ...value...
```

*or* you can do

```
a = if ...condition... then ...value... else ...value...
```

But not both. Most particularly, you can't have `if` without `then` *and* `else`. In Haskell, `if` isn't a statement, it's an expression (rather like the C ternary operator `?:`, if you know of that).

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's when you ask a question that you figure out another way around...
I still don't know why I had that error, however the simple solution is to use an "else" instead.
Which I've done and can now fix the multitude of errors from this function.